# JOptionPane.showOptionDialog not working

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am trying to make a little popup game.
I have added the story and it all worked perfectly fine, untill i added this piece of code:

```
    Object[] choices = null;
    Object[] options = { "Caitlyn", "Warwick", "Teemo", "Olaf", "Ashe" };
      int select = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Who do you want to fight against?", "Champion selection",
            JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, action
            );
```

Now, these options appear on every optiondialog that appears. How do I fix this?

This is my code

```
Object[] choices = null;
    Object[] options = { "Caitlyn", "Warwick", "Teemo", "Olaf", "Ashe" };
      int select = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Who do you want to fight against?", "Champion selection",
            JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, action
            );

      switch (select)
        {
        case 0: 
            int cait = 0;
            cait++;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You will be fighting against the following champion:" + " " + caitlyn.Champion + "  " + "\n She is level" + "  " + caitlyn.Level + " " + "\n And she is a " + caitlyn.Type + "-Champion");

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have started with 2000HP, Caitlyn has 1700HP.");

            // health

            newchamp.health = 2000;
            caitlyn.enemyhealth = 1700;

            //begin

            Object[] choices1 = null;
            Object[] options1 = { "Criticals", "Pure Damage", "Heal 300 points", "Flee" };
              int action = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "What will you do?", "action",
                    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                    null, options, options[0]);

            switch (action)
            {
            case 0: 
                int Criticals = (int) (Math.random()*500);
                Criticals++;
                caitlyn.enemyhealth = (caitlyn.enemyhealth-Criticals);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Caitlyn now has" +" " + caitlyn.enemyhealth + "HP left");
                break;
            case 1:
                int PureDamage = (int) (Math.random()*300);
                PureDamage++;
                caitlyn.enemyhealth = (caitlyn.enemyhealth-PureDamage);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Caitlyn now has" + " " + caitlyn.enemyhealth + "HP left");
                break;
            case 2:
                int heal = 300;
                heal++;
                newchamp.health = (newchamp.health+heal);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "You now have"+ " " + newchamp.health + "HP points!");
                break;
            case 3:
                String flee;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You failed to flee the battle, better luck next round!");
                break;

            }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It's Caitlyn's turn now!");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Caitlyn used a damaging attack!");

            int enemyDamage = (int) (Math.random()*350);
            newchamp.health = (newchamp.health - enemyDamage);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You now have" + " " + newchamp.health +" "+ " HP Left");

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It's your turn again!");


            Object[] choices2 = null;
            Object[] options2 = { "Criticals", "Pure Damage", "Heal 300 points", "Flee" };
              int action1 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "What will you do?", "action",
                    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                    null, options, options[0]);

            switch (action1)
            {
            case 0: 
                int Criticals = (int) (Math.random()*700);
                Criticals++;
                caitlyn.enemyhealth = (caitlyn.enemyhealth-Criticals);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Caitlyn now has" +" " + caitlyn.enemyhealth + "HP left");
                break;
            case 1:
                int PureDamage = (int) (Math.random()*300);
                PureDamage++;
                caitlyn.enemyhealth = (caitlyn.enemyhealth-PureDamage);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Caitlyn now has" + " " + caitlyn.enemyhealth + "HP left");
                break;
            case 2:
                int heal = 300;
                heal++;
                newchamp.health = (newchamp.health+heal);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "You now have"+ " " + newchamp.health + "HP points!");
                break;
            case 3:
                String flee;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have failed to flee the battle, better luck next round!");
                break;

            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It's Caitlyn's turn again!");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Caitlyn hit a critical!");

            int enemyDamage1 = (int) (Math.random()*650);
            newchamp.health = (newchamp.health - enemyDamage);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You now have" + " " + newchamp.health +" "+ " HP Left");
            if (caitlyn.enemyhealth < newchamp.health){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Caitlyn is too injured by your strength to continue this battle. You are victorious!");
            }
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are too injured to continue this battle. You are defeated.");
            break;
        case 1:
            int war = 0;
            war++;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Warwick is still being made. This window will now exit the program.");
            break;
        case 2:
            int teem = 0;
            teem++;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Teemo is still being made. This window will now exit the program.");
            break;
        case 3:
            int ola = 0;
            ola++;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Olaf is still being made. This window will now exit the program.");
            break;
        case 4:
            int ash = 0;
            ash++;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ashe is still being made. This window will now exit the program.");
            break;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: OOT but my advise is to always pass the parent component (window) as the first param to `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog()`. Otherwise you may experience strange issues on some systems or multi-display environments

Comment: are those choices added to JComboBox or JCheckBox later ???, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: It is very strange, I used your code and added a few lines to give a similar behavior to your application and it works fine. Maybe as the first comment saids, you need to specify the window that you will use for your dialog, or try to nullify the options array before show a new message dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you note this part of your code

```
Object[] choices2 = null;
        Object[] options2 = { "Criticals", "Pure Damage", "Heal 300 points", "Flee" };
          int action1 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "What will you do?", "action",
                JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                null, **options**, options[0]);
```

The ** indicate the probable issue. Shouldn't be `options2` ? (there are some other place with the same probable mistake)

Comment: I believe the OP complained of unexpected output, indicating that the program is compiling (although he may have not shown all of the relevant code)

Comment: thanks ben, i overlooked that